# cck value in block

Tags: drupal

Hello 
I am new to drupal. i have created cck for news .on front page i want to display latest news  so I have created region. Now i am creating block to display that news to front page .

can any one  help to display latest news to front page.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use **[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)** module. This is exactly the purpose of this module. And if you are not so aware of all drupal's API, it will really save you a lot of time, and security in your website.

> This tool is essentially a smart query builder that, given enough information, can build the proper query, execute it, and display the results. It has four modes, plus a special mode, and provides an impressive amount of functionality from these modes.
>
> Among other things, Views can be used
>   to generate reports, create summaries,
>   and display collections of images and
>   other content.

It can, of course, generate blocks for you.